# 3ds max fractures in baked textures

Tags: textures, texture-mapping, 3dsmax, 3d-modelling

I'm not sure if stackoverflow is a right place to ask these kinds of questions(I have only asked development questions here) . I need to import a 3d model to my flash program and I need to bake the texture . I baked the texture using this tutorial method
 http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MLsvOASj1zw&list=FLWTAhDxhhT8BYGfGx1aFS7A&index=3&feature=plpp 
and it works , the only problem is that after baking the texture there are some fractures in my object when I render it , seems like 3ds max can't assemble the parts of the baked material image file properly. anyone has any ideas or had any experience with such a problem?
thanks

Comment: can you upload a sample image somewhere please?
It's very hard to understand exactly what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't worked with 3dsmax in a few years, but remember using it to bake textures for papervision scenes.

If the material isn't mapped correctly at all, texture channels might not be matching.
If you use Automatic Unwrap, **make sure the channel on the right matches the channel in the UnwrapUVW modifier**. I tested first without baking.

1. create the model,
2. add the unwrap modifier
3. select polygons, flatten mapping and render UVW Template from the tools in Edit > Unrwap UVW .

I've added the rendered template into the diffuse map, just to make sure the texture is set to the unrwap and noticed it only set up properly on Channel 1. The next step was to remove the template image from the diffuse map and render to texture.

Another tiny issue I had sometimes had, seams were showing, but that can be fixed manually in UV.

HTH

Comment: I found this tutorial and it's specifically for papervision , and it works ! http://www.screencast.com/users/PabloBandin/folders/Default/media/9bc9cf64-92e8-4dde-9d87-8410f4e365e4